# Prove that if 1 = -1 then 2 = 1. (Matematics for computer science)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am doing the problem 1.2 in book Mathematics for computer science by Lehman.
The problem is as follows:

Prove that if 1 = -1 then 2 = 1.

Proof:
Let A be the proposition 1 > 0.
This proposition obviously holds.
Now, let B be the proposition that 1 <= 0. 
Since 1 = -1 and -1 <= 0, B holds as well.
Now, B is the negation of A. So B = not (A).
Finally, let C be the proposition that 2 = 1.
From not (A) we can deduce not (A) or C, or equivalently A => C.
And since A holds, C holds as well.

Does this proof as it stands solve the problem?

Comment: But I am supposed to prove that 2 = 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1=-1$$

multiply with $\frac{1}{2}$

$\implies$

$$\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

add $\frac{3}{2}$

$\implies$

$$2=1$$

Comment: but did you check that $2$ wasn't $0$ before you divided ?

Comment: @mercio You got me, indeed $2=0$ is implied by $1=-1$.

Comment: @mercio Do you have an idea to overcome this issue ?

Comment: the existence of a field with two elements shows that you can't prove this with just the field axioms.However if you assume they are in an ordered field, you can get a contradiction. Anyway it's not very clear what you can or can't do with this question.

Comment: @mercio This is the reason why I always had difficulties to accept the mathematical fact that $A\implies B$ is always true if $A$ is false. It is not clear, whether we can show $B$ by assuming $A$ only using valid statements (except the wrong statement $A$).

Comment: Dividing by $3$ and adding $5/3$ leaves us to show that $2=4/3$ which is obvious since $2=0$. Don't take that seriously, please.

Answer (score 0):

Attacking this problem head on involves a futile attempt, since the limitation 
2 = 0 stops you from manipulating the expression into the wanted proposition.

The approach here is to prove logically the inverse negation validity (which in turn will prove the wanted proposition in the form it appears, since it is just the contraposition method) :

1) Assume 2 != 1.

2) then perform two subtractions:

2 != 1 // -1

2 != 1 // -2

3) we get the two expressions:

1 != 0

0 != -1

4) Adding the two equations results in the assumption proposition negated:

1 != -1

Thus, the contraposition of the original intended proposition proof was shown as being valid and thus by considerations of deductive logic the original proposition is also valid.